# Retrieving nested data with ids in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrive messages from `Message` node. Each message in messages has an Id. The final result I am trying to achieve is just the message for each user or is there ant better way to store the data as I don't need the key for storing messages, but when I don't include the key the old data gets deleted.

[structure of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDgAH.png)

> ```
>  DatabaseReference dbfriends= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
>             dbfriends.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>                     if(dataSnapshot.exists())
>                     {
>                             for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
>                             {
>                                 Log.i("IDDD",productSnapshot.toString());
>                                 Log.i("IDDDDDDDD",productSnapshot.child("Messages").getValue().toString());
>                                    String friend=productSnapshot.child("Username").getValue().toString();
>                                    Log.i("This is friend",friend.toString());
>                                     friends.add(friend);
>
>                             }
> ```

Comment: in your code you are retrieving the messages..

Comment: @PeterHaddad but when it returns it returns the unique id too

Answer (score 0):

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messagesRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("Messages");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String sender = ds.child("sender").getValue(String.class);
            String message = ds.child("message").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, sender + ": " + message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
messagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
Jeffy: Alic how r you?
Jeffy: Alic how r you?
```

If you also need the key, simply use:

```
String key = ds.getKey();
```

Comment: Hi CryBaby! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Yeah I tried your solution it works fine... Thanks for your help :)